# Drawing flicker free line

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

In delphi there was a ability to redraw a line in xor mode ,in this mode pen merged with backcolor and caused to hide the line,and if we had many color in background the line redrew with that color,how can i do same thing in c#,
i don't wanna redraw line with backcolor again to hide line
also i should say
i want to draw line in panel mousemove event to connect one rectangle shape to another

Comment: It is still supported although not by GDI+.  Use ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine().

Comment: i know,but im looking something in graphic class

Comment: You must have noticed the "not by GDI+" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .net world, you basically redraw the backcolor and redraw your line.  You can use DoubleBuffering to help minimize the flickering.

If you are dead set on trying to go old school, look into the [SetRop2](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.setrop2) api call.

Comment: redrawing previous line is'nt good idea, it causes to redraw on some other shapes like lines and ..., with a different color ,im looking something like MsPaint line drawing ,clearing the background and redrawing all object isnt good idea

Comment: Absolutely, and SetRop2 is exactly what ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine does behind the scene.